# Echo or "cat" parameters passed into a function call in R

Tags: r, function

Consider the following:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  cat(deparse(x))
  cat("\n")
  cat(x)
}

y <- 1:3

foo(y)
# 1:3
# 1 2 3
```

Desired output:

```
foo(y)
# You passed variable "y" with 1:3
# 1 2 3
```

How can I `cat()` some output that tells me the name of the value that was passed into `foo()`?

---

As a follow-up for understanding some subtle differences, how could I create `foo2()` which would produce the following:

```
foo2 <- function(?) { ? }

foo2(unique(iris$Species))
# You passed "unique(iris$Species)"
# [1] setosa     versicolor virginica 
# Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

This question stems from my limited understanding of `substitute`, `match.call`, `eval`, `bquote`, `parse`, and `deparse` - so feel free to expand any answers to include additional explanation on how all of those fit together.

Comment: Try `cat(paste('You passed variable',  deparse(substitute(x)), 'with', deparse(x)))`

Comment: @akrun That works for the first example +1. Curious how to adapt this to `foo2()`? Moreover, I and others would greatly appreciate an answer with explanation of how/why this works to build some intuition per my final paragraph above.

Comment: I haven't looked at your second question.  It is better to ask one question at a time :-)

Comment: You might be looking for `match.call`

Comment: If you are okay with `print`, then `foo2 <- function(x){
cat(paste('You passed variable', dQuote(deparse(substitute(x)))), '\n')
print(x)
}`

Comment: One version that should work in both cases would be `foo <- function(...){
v1 <- deparse(list(...)[[1]]);
 dots <- match.call(expand.dots=TRUE)[[2]];
if(grepl('[$]', deparse(dots))){
  cat(paste('Your passed variable', dQuote(deparse(dots))), '\n');
print(list(...)[[1]]);
}
else
{
 cat(paste('You passed variable', dQuote(deparse(dots)), 'with', v1), '\n');
cat(c(...), '\n')
}
}`  I am leaving this as comment as I couldn't find a way with `cat` for the second case.